# Call PathRestriction in a DSL in the sandbox mode

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

My goal is to exclude some git regions from SCM trigger. But I have some constraints.

I have to run my DSL jobs in the sandbox mode.

[pathRestriction](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/git/hudson/plugins/git/extensions/impl/PathRestriction.html) fixes my issue. But I couldn't find a way to call it in sandbox mode.

PathRestriction is not implemented in DSL plugin. Therefore I can't use extensions contexts.

Configure blocks works if it doesn't run in sandbox mode.

```
pipelineJob("jobname") {
//..
    definition {
        cpsScm {
            scm {
                git {
                    //..
                    extensions {
                        relativeTargetDirectory("myRootPath") // works because implemented [in DSL plugin][2]
                        pathRestriction('includedPaths', 'excludedPaths') // not implemented in dsl plugin
                    }
                    // code below doesn't allowed in sandbox mode
                    configure { node ->
                        node / 'extensions' / 'hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.PathRestriction' {
                            excludedRegions 'excludedPaths'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need a workaround until  "pathRestriction" is added to job DSL.

I also created [a Jenkins Jira ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50786) to implement pathRestriction to the job DSL plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [configure blocks](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block),
Something like that:

```
pipelineJob(jobName) {
    concurrentBuild(true)
    logRotator {
        numToKeep(5)
    }
    description("description")
    triggers {
        scm('H/3 * * * *')
    }
    definition {
        cpsScm {
            lightweight(true)
            scm {
                git{
                    branch("master")
                    remote {
                        credentials(credID)
                        url(gitUrl)
                        scriptPath(scriptName)
                    }
                    configure {
                        it / extensions / "hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.PathRestriction" {
                            includedRegions("JenkinsFiles/JobDSL/.*\\.groovy")
                            excludedRegions('')
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```